# Bad Truecypt External Drive- how to recover

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, truecrypt

Under Windows 10. TC 7.1a

After correct password entry, external WD drive shows up as a Y drive as follows:

Volume: \Device\Harddisk2\Partition 1
Size 223 GB AES
Type Hidden

But when clicking on it in windows explorer, get the errors:
"You need to format the disk in drive Y..."   and on Cancel
"Y:\ is not accessible..does not contain a recognized..."

Is there any way to recover my data?

Thank you.

Comment: The data is encrypted if Truecrypt isn’t mounting the drive you have absolutely no way to access your data

Comment: So the fact that it is showing up as a drive letter does not give any hope?

Comment: First, confirm that the physical disk is healthy, by checking its SMART stats. If the disk is healthy, try mounting the volume in TC. From there, right click on the volume in the mount grid, and select "Check Filesystem". This will run `chkdsk` on the volume. from the chkdsk output, you can determine whether and to what extent the filesystem is damaged. I don't recommend you use the "Repair Filesystem" option, until you have backed up the disks contents in case things go awry. Data recovery is a very risky proposition, so don't try to cheap out on backups during the process.